# Weird problem with Visual Studio - when I change the name of a unit test, it does not update 

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I've run into a weird problem with Unit Tests in Visual Studio 2010 that I can't solve (is this a bug in Visual Studio?).

If I edit the name of a unit test, it is not updating in the "Test List Editor" view. If I add a unit test using the normal method, it doesn't add it to the list of unit tests.

Any ideas on what might be possibly be causing this, and perhaps brainstorming some method to redo my Unit Test project to fix this problem?

Comment: Which Unit Test runner are you using? It sounds like a refresh issue. Try 'Clean' your solution and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I have ReSharper installed, and it unexpectedly took over the default unit testing framework provided by Visual Studio 2010, when an auto version upgrade took place. I am currently running the unit tests using the ReSharper unit testing plugin, and everything works fine. This is not to say that it's necessarily ReSharper's fault, I did opt in to use the enhanced unit testing framework when I installed it a month ago (and I can opt out by switching it off in options).